Bazel takes forever to compile a simple protobuf
Any idea what might be happening here, it is a simple proto message but it is over 10 min and compilation is still going bazel build :person_proto
Advise will be appreciated
load("@rules_proto//proto:defs.bzl", "proto_library")
proto_library(
  name = "person_proto",
  srcs = ["person.proto"],
)



It looks like it is compiling the Google C++ protobuf library, not just the single proto file. The C++ library is rather large and slow to build, but hopefully the tool will only build it on first use.

Please don't post images of textual content. Those can't be conveniently copied into a file to try it out.

This is because Bazel is building all of Protobuf from source. You might want to check out these pre-built protoc toolchains which are remarkably faster: https://github.com/aspect-build/toolchains_protoc
